# OnClick in for-loop

Tags: android, for-loop, onclick

OnClick in a loop does not function properly...

The error refers to an excess of array values, I don't know why.

Is there a way to make OnClick function normally with a loop?

---

Logcat

> 2020-02-08 17:58:36.295 20307-20307/com.example.pagevalue_shift_2
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

```
Process: com.example.pagevalue_shift_2, PID: 20307

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=3

    at com.example.pagevalue_shift_2.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:32)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
    at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

---

//error code

```
package com.example.pagevalue_shift_2;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;

import android.widget.Button;

import android.widget.TextView;

import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.pagevalue_shift_2.R;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView[] textView = new TextView[3];
    String a[] = {
        "a",
        "b",
        "c"
    };
    int i;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView[0] = findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView[1] = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        textView[2] = findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

            textView[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), a[i], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //error occurred
                }
            });
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: make like that and do your stuff

for(i =0; i<3; i++){
 textView[i] = new TextView();
    }

Comment: textView[0] = findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    textView[1] = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    textView[2] = findViewById(R.id.textView3);

remove these create dynamic means  then why you make like that

Comment: try to remove you "int i" variable from activity and put it as a local variable inside a loop like this: for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { ... }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You are creating an anonymous class (View.OnClickListener) for each
>   textView, the onClick() method within that class has a different scope
>   than the method onCreate(), therefore it has no access to
>   local variable i.
>
> An anonymous class cannot access local variables in its enclosing
>   scope that are not declared as final or effectively final.

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    textView[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        final int j = i;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), a[j] + " ", Toast.LENGTH_SHOR).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

value of `int i` is outer immutable variable and will be equal to `3` after the for loop is completed. Hence, all clicks after that will trigger same code regardles:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),a[3],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

If you want your code to work correctly, you have to copy the value of `i` and do not depend on the global mutable value. This code below  will do what you want:

```
for(i =0; i<3; i++){
    textView[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
              int x = i;
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),a[x],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); occurred
         }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can give id to text view and get it like below -

```
for(i =0; i<3; i++){
textView[i].setId(i);
        textView[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),a[textView[i].getId()],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//error occurred
            }
        });
    }
```